# How does Flurry of Blows work when wielding two weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, monk, attack

I'm trying to understand how FoB interacts with wielding a weapon in each hand. When using Flurry of Blows while wielding two weapons, do I make an attack with each weapon for each additional attack?

For instance, let's say I have a 4th-level Monk. To calculate FoB, I treat my BaB as 4, add one attack, and subtract 2 from both attacks, which gives me +2/+2. If wielding a single weapon or my unarmed strike, this is quite straightforward; I get two attacks at +2 each. If I'm wielding a Monk weapon in each hand, though, do I get two attacks at +2 each with both weapons, for four total attacks? With the Two-Weapon Fighting feat chain, it's specified that the additional attacks are for your off-hand weapon, but this isn't made clear in the Flurry of Blows description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Flurry of Blows modifies your full-attack

It adds additional attacks, and applies a penalty. It is otherwise a normal full-attack like any other.

This means you may use any weapon you have available for any given attack. If you are holding two weapons, you can use one or the other for each attack you’d normally have.

Note that this is *exactly the same* as when you *don’t* use Flurry of Blows. If you have multiple attacks for whatever reason (BAB +6 or higher, the *haste* spell, whatever), you can use any weapon you have available for any given attack as you please.

On the flip side, you do not have any more attacks, normally, than you would with a single weapon. You simply get the attacks you would otherwise have. Those can be the ordinary attacks of your full-attack, or extra attacks from Flurry of Blows, or whatever. Simply *having* two weapons does not give you extra attacks.

To get extra attacks, you have to use the Two-Weapon Fighting combat option (and then you are subject to its penalties and restrictions). In particular, Two-Weapon Fighting is an **exception** to this “any weapon for any attack” bit. Note that this is more than just having two weapons; you have to actually choose to use Two-Weapon Fighting, or none of the following applies. ***When you do choose to use Two-Weapon Fighting***, it changes your full-attack (much as Flurry of Blows does): it grants an extra attack and applies a penalty, and it also applies a special restriction on which weapon you can use for which attack: specifically, your bonus attack from Two-Weapon Fighting has to be a different weapon than the one you are otherwise using.

Furthermore, under Pathfinder rules, Flurry of Blows ***is*** Two-Weapon Fighting (except it doesn’t actually require you to use two weapons). As such, the idea is you cannot use it ***and*** Two-Weapon Fighting at the same time. If this is the case, there is *absolutely zero benefit* to having two weapons, except I guess the ability to pick which one you want.  You’re better off with a more-powerful single weapon than splitting your wealth between two.

***Unfortunately***, the rules here are ***notoriously vague*** and have required numerous amendments, explanations, Paizo contradicting themselves several times, and finally overruling previous rules entirely because they never made sense. This is actually one of the most famous fiascoes in Pathfinder history, and the rules are left a mess as a result. I suggest just returning to the 3.5 rules, before all this started: Flurry of Blows and Two-Weapon Fighting are completely separate things, combine them if you want (taking *even more* penalties and gaining *even more* attacks). This is still a bad idea, since it is a very weak option, but at least the rules are clear, make sense, and there’s actually, theoretically, a benefit to dual-wielding as a monk.